# How do I deploy a rosdep mirror?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosdep, ros-kinetic, github

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Github is starting to throttle my requests to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro . How do I deploy a mirror of such a package index and tell `rosdep` to consume it?

Edit: responding the obvious question; it's probably in the neighborhood of 5000 invocations daily from my employer's office. I've already taken steps eliminate the ones I make during sundry container initialization, but there are some that I can't eliminate --- notably the one issued by `bloom-release` when I bloom my projects.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338122/how-do-i-deploy-a-rosdep-mirror?/) by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 193 on 2019-11-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-20**:
Just to get some sense of scale here: how many package (re)builds are you running? Or how many packages are you building per time-unit?

I'm not aware of `build.ros.org` using any mirror or cache for `ros/rosdistro` specifically, so I'm wondering what it would take for Github to start throttling you.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-11-20**:
Wow, that's a lot of calls. Can you confirm which operations are problematic, is it the rosdep updates that are failing? Those should not be necessary to call that often as the rosdep database doesn't change that often. Most rosdistro operations are designed to use the cache.

It would be possible to add an enhancement to rosdep to use a github token to do authenticated fetching with a much higher limit. And bloom could also be enhanced to do the same as well as pass the credentials through.

For reference [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3708) implies that this is governed by the unauthenticated API rate limit of 60/hour, Authenticating will get you up to 5000/hour. [GitHub API rate limiting](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-21**:\

> it's probably in the neighborhood of 5000 invocations daily from my employer's office

can you say anything about what you're actually doing that requires that many `rosdep update`s?

> there are some that I can't eliminate --- notably the one issued by `bloom-release` when I bloom my projects.

5000 `bloom-release`s per day (?).

**Comment by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on 2019-11-21**:
There's about 50 invocations to `bloom-release` daily. I've been able to eliminate all other invocations to `rosdep update`. Now, I `rosdep update` as `root` during the construction of a build environment and then copy `~root/.ros` to `~luser` when I wish to build catkin projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As a direct answer to your question you can setup your own rosdep sources. See the documentation here: https://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/sources_list.html

But I have to agree with @gvdhoorn that we have used this a lot and have not experienced throttling from github on our CI setups. How often are you calling rosdep update?

I put together a quick Dockerfile to demo how to use a local copy:

```
FROM ros
# pull a copy of the rosdistro
RUN mkdir -p /cache && cd /cache && git clone https://github.com/ros/rosdistro.git -b master --depth 1
# Update it to self reference
RUN sed -i s#https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/#file:///cache/rosdistro/# /cache/rosdistro/rosdep/sources.list.d//20-default.list
# Tell the local environment to use the local instance of rosdistro
ENV ROSDISTRO_INDEX_URL="file:///cache/rosdistro/index-v4.yaml"
# Tell rosdep where to look for sources
ENV ROSDEP_SOURCE_PATH=/cache/rosdistro/rosdep/sources.list.d
# Clear system sources for clarity. They will be overridden anyway, but to show for this demo they're not being used.
RUN rm -rf /etc/ros/rosdep

# Show rosdep working using local resources
CMD rosdep update
```

You can host the clone of the rosdistro anywhere you want. it's convenient for this demo to be on the filesystem.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on 2019-11-20**:
I can certainly replace the default list...

```
https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
```

...with something that references the same gbpdistro and yaml content under `file:///` URIs instead of `https://` URIs. But when I try that trick with the `DEFAULT_INDEX_URL`...

https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdistro/blob/838099d161b15940eb102c0c13d99675f6752562/src/rosdistro/__init__.py#L68

...it errors out looking for non-existent files on my host. Any ideas what's happening there?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-11-20**:
What are you doing to change the DEFAULT_INDEX_URL? What are you running? And what are the errors?

**Comment by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on 2019-11-21**:
Here's a `Dockerfile` demonstrating what I mean: https://hastebin.com/raw/ocitiqujeg

The error produced is as follows:

```
    ERROR: error loading sources list:
    <urlopen error <urlopen error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/rosdep/crystal/distribution.yaml'>(file:///var/lib/rosdep/crystal/distribution.yaml)>
```

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-11-21**:
I saw your hastebin posting this morning, but now it' won't load on a heroku error

Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail

**Comment by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on 2019-11-22**:
Shucks. Try this one: https://gist.github.com/rubicks/0a9e2ad9f08a22acd23ac95ee3f2648e

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-11-22**:
I updated my answer with an example of how to use rosdep using a local copy of the rosdistro in a Dockerfile

**Comment by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on 2019-11-25**:
That will certainly work for my purposes --- thanks very much.